# Django Development: PyMongo or MongoEngine ... and why?

Tags: python, django, orm, mongodb

Trying to decide between these two, looking for some solid feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MongoEngine](http://mongoengine.org/docs/v0.4/) is an ORM that wraps [PyMongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/). Using PyMongo directly will probably be marginally faster/more efficient. If you really like Django's ORM you'll probably like MongoEngine. Look at their documentation, play with their APIs and decide for yourself. I rather like both. You could also take a look at [MongoKit](http://namlook.github.com/mongokit/index.html) which is another ORM that wraps PyMongo. This is more a question of should I use an ORM or not? Even if you do go with MongoEngine, make sure to read PyMongo and MongoDB's documentation! You'll still need to understand how MongoDB works if you want to write decent applications with it.